# Как хранить изображения на жестком диске (Servlet)

Tags: java, servlet

Я написал программу которая хранит изображения студентов в web/images в самой программе. Как сделать так, чтобы он хранил его в любом месте допустим (Диск С/Pictures.....)

Вот мой код 
Addstudent Servlet

```
package servlet;

import dao.DatabaseDAO;
import entity.Student;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;


@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 2, // 2MB
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50)   // 50MB
public class AddStudentServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Name of the directory where uploaded files will be saved, relative to the
     * web application directory.
     */
    private static final String SAVE_DIR = "images";

    private DatabaseDAO dao;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        dao = new DatabaseDAO();
    }

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // gets absolute path of the web application
        String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");

        // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
        String savePath = appPath + SAVE_DIR;

        // creates the save directory if it does not exists
        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdir();
        }

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
        String fileName;

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
            String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
            for (String item : items) {
                String ss = item.trim();
                if (ss.startsWith("filename")) {
                    try {
                        int id = dao.insertStudentIntoDB(name, surname);
                        fileName = String.valueOf(id);
                        part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
                        request.setAttribute("message", "Студент добавлен.");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        request.setAttribute("message", "Ошибка при добавлении студента!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<Student> students = dao.readAllStudentsFromDB();
        request.setAttribute("students", students);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("ShowAllStudent.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    private String extractName(String s) {
        return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length() - 1);
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Другой сервлет MyStudent

```
package servlet;

import dao.DatabaseDAO;
import entity.Student;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

import java.util.List;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DatabaseDAO dao;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        dao = new DatabaseDAO();
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = request.getParameter("actionname");

        if (action.equals("RemoveStudent")) {
            int id = parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            boolean deleted = dao.deleteStudentFromDB(id);

            String message;
            if (deleted) {
                message = "Студент удален.";
            } else {
                message = "Студент не существует";
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", message);

            List<Student> students = dao.readAllStudentsFromDB();
            request.setAttribute("students", students);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("ShowAllStudent.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        if (action.equals("ShowAllStudent")) {
            List<Student> students = dao.readAllStudentsFromDB();
            request.setAttribute("students", students);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("ShowAllStudent.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас ведь есть в коде переменная, в которой путь хранится `// constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file`

Comment: я пытался но там ошибка, может не так правильно писал

Comment: Может и не так. А что за ошибка?

Comment: Это нужно в вопросе описывать, а не чтобы у вас выпытывали в комментарии -- что пытались сделать, что не получилось. Например, у вас в новом пути сколько папок идут от корневого диска? Если больше чем одна метод mkdir не сработает, нужно mkdirs вызывать. А мб у вас с путем какая-то лажа. Попробуйте так: `    String savePath = "C:/MyWebPicture";
    File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
    }`. С mkdirs у вас сработает даже если куча папок будет, например "C:/MyWebPicture/abc/123"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените код под `// creates the save directory if it does not exists`, например на:

```
String savePath = "C:/MyWebPicture";
File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
    fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
}
```

---

Не знаю что у вас за проблема, но думаю или в пути, или в **mkdir**. **mkdir** создаст только одну папку в пути, если нужно создать несколько папок, вложенных друг в друга, метод не выполнится, поэтому нужно использовать **mkdirs**.

Путь в **savePath** можете после проверки работы алгоритма поменять на свой